# Send_keys function triggers error message: 'Message: element not interactable'

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using Selenium to fill out this HTML form, but when it comes to inputting the data it says 'element not interactable'. I am able to click on the element however actually sending a string produces an error. How can I fix this?

```
driver.get('https://www.masmovil.es/cobertura-fibra-optica-campos/')
prov = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="province"]'))
prov.select_by_index(32)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="town"]').send_keys('1')
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the page you are accessing there are 2 elements that are returned with the selector `by_xpath('//*[@id="town"]')`, one is a "mm-ui-autocomplete", the other one is an "input".

the "mm-ui-autocomplete" is not visible nor interactable to a real user, that's probably what's throwing the exception you're having, and selenium always takes the first match when there's more than one element returned by the selector, so, assuming you want to type something on the "Localidad" field, it is selecting the wrong element.

Try changing your selector to `by_xpath('//input[@id="town"]')` and see if it works.

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes thank you! I feel so stupid, i had spent a while trying to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with this css selector :

```
input[id='town']
```

**code** :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[id='town']").send_keys('1')
```

The xpath `(//*[@id="town"])` you have used has two entries :

one with `mm-ui-autocomplete` tag and one with `input` tag.

Always give preference to css selector over xpath. It's more stable then xpath.

In case you would not want to use css selector, then you can use xpath like this :

```
//input[@id='town']
```

Code :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='town']").send_keys('1')
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it happens that the `find_element` was not working before the frontend finished loading.

I solved this by adding `sleep(2)` before the `find_element_by_xpath`. You will need to import the function by `from time import sleep`.